# can i make a form with many inputs and dropdowns show an alert if they have not saved data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms

can i make a form with many inputs and dropdowns show an alert if they have not saved data?
I only want to show the alert or make a save button perhaps change color or flash if they make any changes to any inputs (about 200 inputs and drop downs in a grid). is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You probably can, but you should tell us what you've tried so far. It'll be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a listener for `onChange` (triggered by modifying dropdown selections) and `oninput` (triggered by modifying an input) events.

If you're using jQuery, you can handle both cases with the `$(selector).change()` method: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

```
$("input,select,textarea").change(function(){
  alert("Please remember to save your data!");  // eww
  $("input[type='submit']").addClass('warn');
});
```

Note that an alert triggered every time a user makes a change would create for a horrible UX...  your idea of altering the save button color would work better.  You could do this by toggling a CSS class, like above.

Comment: I had to make the document wrapper to get this to work- here is my code          
[code]     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input,select,textarea").change(function () {
            $("#<%=btnSaveDataFull.clientid %>").addClass('SkinPulgin_button_update');
        });
     });[/code]

Comment: Yes, an event binding won't do anything if its DOM target does not (yet) exist.  To address this, you can wrap your event listeners within a document ready listener (as you have done) or place the event bindings at the foot of your document.